Is it possible to create a transaction as an admin and send it but with someone else paying for the gas fees?
I have a mintToken method in my smart contract that is onlyAdmin.
The problem I have is that I don't want to pay for the transactions for my users every time I execute this function (and it also can't be public, because there are restrictions to call this mint method). In addition to this, I can't whitelist addresses to call the function because I want to keep it flexible and make sure that a user that is able to mint can connect any wallet to claim their tokens (not a predefined one or known beforehand).
Is it possible to call this method with gas fees paid by the user but having the signature and the sender of the transaction as the admin? Is there a way of achieving this behaviour? Maybe using account abstraction?

Sorry, I think I misunderstood your initial question. Let me delete my response.

Do you think what I want to achieve is possible thou?


Is it possible to call this method with gas fees paid by the user

You can make your smart contract act based on the message signed by your centralised server. This message is a smart contract function parameter the user calls.
Usually this is done for the whitelisting users (KYC), but it is can be done also done to make users to pay for the gas.

Thank you! Can you please point me to an example of a similar implementation?

https://github.com/miohtama/smart-contracts/blob/8892e85d1c75994871a0fa14eb8c03016db39d88/contracts/KYCCrowdsale.sol#L49
